# Why is the event in my controller class not firing

Tags: java, css, events, javafx, fxml

The event method that I'm talking about is changeBackgroundScreen. The button is being covered by a background image in one of my css file. At first I thought it was the background blocking the button from being interact with. I took the background image off and it still didn't work. Now I have no clue.

**Here is a portion of the FXML File For you to focus on:**

```
 <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="200">
      <children>
          <Button fx:id="optionButton1" onAction="#changeBackgroundScreen" prefWidth="80" prefHeight="50" id="SmallBlueBackground1"/>
          <Button fx:id="optionButton2" onAction="#changeBackgroundScreen" prefWidth="80" prefHeight="50" id="SmallBlueBackground2"/>
          <Button fx:id="optionButton3" onAction="#changeBackgroundScreen" prefWidth="80" prefHeight="50" id="SmallBlueBackground3"/>
      </children>
</HBox>
```

**Here is the entire FXML File if you're interested:**

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.net.URL?>

<StackPane  fx:id="Optionmenu" id="BlueBackground1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="millionairetriviagame.OptionscreenController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@BackgroundImages.css" />
    </stylesheets>
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@ButtonLayout.css"/>
    </stylesheets>
    <children>
        <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" spacing="20">
            <ImageView>
                <image>
                    <Image url="@ImageFiles/MillionaireLogo1.png"/>
                </image>
            </ImageView>
            <Label text="Click to Change the Background Color" style="-fx-font-style: Italic;"  textFill="white">
                <font>
                    <javafx.scene.text.Font name="sans-serif" size="20" />  
                </font>
            </Label>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="200">
                <children>
                    <Button fx:id="optionButton1" onAction="#changeBackgroundScreen" prefWidth="80" prefHeight="50" id="SmallBlueBackground1"/>
                    <Button fx:id="optionButton2" onAction="#changeBackgroundScreen" prefWidth="80" prefHeight="50" id="SmallBlueBackground2"/>
                    <Button fx:id="optionButton3" onAction="#changeBackgroundScreen" prefWidth="80" prefHeight="50" id="SmallBlueBackground3"/>
                </children>
            </HBox>
        </VBox>
        <HBox alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" spacing="10"  >
            <children>
                <Button fx:id="backToMain"  prefWidth="200" prefHeight="30" onAction="#goToTheMainMenu"  text="Back to the Main Menu" styleClass="ButtonLayout"> 
                    <shape>
                        <javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle  width="200" height="30" arcHeight="30" arcWidth="30" />  
                    </shape>
                </Button>
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </children>
</StackPane>
```

**Here is my controller Class**

```
package millionairetriviagame;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class OptionscreenController implements Initializable, ControllingScreens
{
    private ScreenNavigator controller;
    private MediaPlayer optionMenuPlayer;
    @FXML private Button backToMain;
    private BooleanProperty isDisabled;
    @FXML private StackPane Optionmenu;
    @FXML private Button optionButton1;
    @FXML private Button optionButton2;
    @FXML private Button optionButton3;
    @FXML private StackPane mainMenu;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        configureProperties();
        playSong();
    }

    private void configureProperties()
    {
        isDisabled = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        backToMain.disableProperty().bind(isDisabled);
    }

    @Override
    public void setScreenParent(ScreenNavigator parentScreen)
    {
        controller = parentScreen;
    }

    private void playSong()
    {
        Media optionIntroTheme = new Media(getClass().getResource("/millionairetriviagame/AudioFiles/OptionMenuMusic.mp3").toExternalForm());
        optionMenuPlayer = new MediaPlayer(optionIntroTheme);
        optionMenuPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        optionMenuPlayer.setVolume(0.1);
        optionMenuPlayer.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
    }

    @FXML private void changeBackgroundScreen(ActionEvent event)
    {
        try
        {
            FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(MillionaireTriviaGame.MAIN));
            myLoader.load();
            mainMenu = myLoader.getRoot();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(OptionscreenController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 

        if(optionButton2.isPressed())
        {
            mainMenu.setId("BlueBackground2");
            Optionmenu.setId("BlueBackground2");
        }
    }

    @FXML private void goToTheMainMenu(ActionEvent event)
    {
        isDisabled.setValue(true);
        optionMenuPlayer.stop();
        controller.loadScreen(MillionaireTriviaGame.MAINSCREENID, MillionaireTriviaGame.MAIN);
        controller.setScreen(MillionaireTriviaGame.MAINSCREENID);
    }
}
```

**Here is my CSS File if you need to look at it as well.**

```
#BlueBackground1
{
    -fx-background-image: url("/millionairetriviagame/ImageFiles/BlueBackgroundColor.jpg");
}

#BlueBackground2
{
    -fx-background-image: url("/millionairetriviagame/ImageFiles/BlueBackgroundColor2.jpg");
}

#SmallBlueBackground1
{
    -fx-background-image: url("/millionairetriviagame/ImageFiles/BlueBackgroundColor.jpg");
    -fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
    -fx-background-size: 80 50;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0, 0, 0;
}

#SmallBlueBackground2
{
    -fx-background-image: url("/millionairetriviagame/ImageFiles/BlueBackgroundColor2.jpg");
    -fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
    -fx-background-size: 80 50;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0, 0, 0;
}

#SmallBlueBackground3
{
    -fx-background-image: url("/millionairetriviagame/ImageFiles/BlueBackgroundColor3.jpg");
    -fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
    -fx-background-size: 80 50;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0, 0, 0;
}
```

Here is a visual

[image: OptionMenu]

Comment: Are you sure the method is not getting invoked? Maybe the logic is just wrong and you are not seeing any change.

Comment: The `HBox` is covering on the `VBox` and therefore your event cannot delegate to the button in the VBox.

Comment: @James_D Nope it is not getting invoked because I debugged it using breakpoints and it didn't even make it to the function.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Well I need  the Hbox to be there else it won't have that horizontal look.

Comment: Two things: first, I think `option2Button.isPressed()` will always return false; the button needs to be released before the `ActionEvent` is fired. Second, you load `mainMenu` from the FXML file, but you never do anything with it, so I don't know what changes you expect to see in the UI. Obviously if you're certain the method isn't getting invoked, then these are secondary, but I don't think this method does anything that changes the UI anyway.

Comment: Why does your function changeBackgroundScreen have a parameter?

Comment: @James_D You misunderstand James. I'm trying to test if the event fires at all regardless of what is inside. If the event was firing, it would have exceuted the breakpoints that I laid out for the program to perform but it didn't. This means that the event is not triggering.

Comment: @DustinCharles Yes You're right I don't need that.

Comment: No, I understood that. I was just pointing out that the method doesn't actually do anything, which you will presumably need to know at some point. I posted a comment rather than an answer because I knew this didn't answer the question.

Comment: @LuisAverhoff You need the `ActionEvent` is you want to make use of the event reference.

Comment: Ok then point taken.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Well the program still works fine without it.

Comment: @LuisAverhoff Because your program doesn't need (make use of) the event.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Well I guess i'll make use of it when I need it.

Comment: Okay.  I tried it out in SceneBuilder, and ItachiUchihia is correct.  Your last HBox contains the button "Back to Main Menu".  But because you are using a StackPane, that last HBox lays on top of the 3 other buttons.  One option is to  move your last HBox ( containing the button "Back to Main Menu") to a position inside of the VBox.

This did not change the visual layout on my end.

<StackPane>
...

Comment: @DustinCharles ya uchihia already figured out a solution to the problem. But thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

The problem is with your layout. You have a `StackPane` with VBox (containing the buttons which fire the `changeBackgroundScreen` methods) and on top of that you have a `HBox` (with a single button, aligned to bottom right).

At the first glance everything might just look cool. But, remember `VBox` and `HBox` are layouts which *fill their parent*. So, even if you can't see, the HBox lies on top of your buttons in the VBox blocking all the interactions.

### Solution

A more complex solution would be to use something other than a `StackPane` because I don't really see the need of it. But, since you already have the layout, lets go with something which needs little tweaking to the layout.

A very simple solution would be to move the `HBox` into the `VBox`. This way, there is no blocking layer. But, since you want the button to *stick to the bottom-right* of the scene, we will use a `Region` in between the children of the VBox and set the `VGrow as Always`. This will *push* the newly added HBox to the bottom of the scene and make it stick there no matter what your scene size is.

### Complete FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.net.URL?>

<StackPane id="BlueBackground1" fx:id="Optionmenu" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" fx:controller="millionairetriviagame.OptionscreenController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@BackgroundImages.css" />
    </stylesheets>
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@ButtonLayout.css" />
    </stylesheets>
    <children>
        <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" spacing="20">
            <ImageView>
                <image>
                    <Image url="@ImageFiles/MillionaireLogo1.png" />
                </image>
            </ImageView>
            <Label style="-fx-font-style: Italic;" text="Click to Change the Background Color" textFill="white">
                <font>
                    <javafx.scene.text.Font name="sans-serif" size="20" />  
                </font>
            </Label>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="200">
                <children>
                    <Button id="SmallBlueBackground1" fx:id="optionButton1" onAction="#changeBackgroundScreen" prefHeight="50" prefWidth="80" />
                    <Button id="SmallBlueBackground2" fx:id="optionButton2" onAction="#changeBackgroundScreen" prefHeight="50" prefWidth="80" />
                    <Button id="SmallBlueBackground3" fx:id="optionButton3" onAction="#changeBackgroundScreen" prefHeight="50" prefWidth="80" />
                </children>
            </HBox>
         <Region prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
         <HBox alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" spacing="10">
            <children>
                <Button fx:id="backToMain" onAction="#goToTheMainMenu" prefHeight="30" prefWidth="200" styleClass="ButtonLayout" text="Back to the Main Menu"> 
                    <shape>
                        <javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle arcHeight="30" arcWidth="30" height="30" width="200" />  
                    </shape>
                </Button>
            </children>
           </HBox>
        </VBox>
    </children>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: Excellent Explanation and answer.